# How can I send parameters to a sub-index page?

Tags: apache, indexing, friendly-url

I have a homepage, for example: `www.example.com`.

There is a url like this:

`www.example.com/subdirectory/page.php?var1=A&var2=B`

It's a long url, so I changed it like this:

`www.example.com/subdirectory/page/A/B`

as well as I config the .htaccess file:

> `<Files page>`
>
> `ForceType application/x-httpd-php`
>
> `</Files>`

However, I assume it's also quite long. If the "page.php" change to "index.php", the "page" seems to disappear, just like this:

`www.example.com/subdirectory/A/B`

But I don't know how to achieve.

Is omitted **'page'** possible? How can I just do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this. It will allow you to present a pretty URL to users and then rewrite it in Apache. You could use www.example.com/subdirectory/page/A/B on all pages and then rewrite it to www.example.com/subdirectory/page.php?var1=A&var2=B internally.

Comment: Chris, you're right. However, if using `mod_rewrite`, it's a 'redirect'. I still have a long url. I don't think it's a friendly url for SEO. Actually, using the .htaccess I've written above, you can get a shorter url, as well as be detected by search engine. thanks your answer.